# Vue3 how to minimize, maximize and close modal or component to bottom of page (like windows)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, inertiajs

Let say in vue page has child component or a modal where user can minimize to bottom, maximize and close but keep state of those components until user close. (behave like windows)

I try to find a solution on how i can implement this logic but i didn't get a solution after googling for a while.
please if you have any working example i will appreciate thank you.

see this image example
[image]

Comment: You'll have to write something yourself

Comment: that's not different from other Vue code. when you minimize windows the components are alive and keep their state.